# SASS, @import and make it abstract

Tags: sass

Is there any way to @import a file and make all the classe it contains abstract ?

Let me show an example to explain :

```
@import "bootstrap"; //Do something magic to make all classes abstract
.my-bem__custom{
  @extend .btn
}
```

It should output a css file this way :

```
//Not any bootstrap stuff here
.my-bem__custom {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  Sass has nothing like that.  If it did, it would be referenced in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, any idea if an other CSS extension (like LESS) can do that?

Comment: I do not use other CSS Preprocessors.  I suggest you *check their documentation* if you want to know.